# Chromium error with SPDY when using Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, sdk, spdy

I develop a mobile application with HTML5 + Cordova (Phonegap) using Facebook Javascript SDK for iOs and Android.
I implement it like this :

```
FB.api(
{
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
},
function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // some code
});
```

It worked for several months on Android & iOs, until yesterday, on Android.
An error occurs when the call to the api is doing and the callback function is not called.

Here is the error from LogCat in eclipse :

> 02-26 12:27:10.526: W/chromium(22379):
>   external/chromium/net/spdy/spdy_session.cc:1246:
>   [0226/122710:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(1246)] Could not parse Spdy
>   Control Frame Header. 02-26 12:27:10.526: D/chromium(22379): Unknown
>   chromium error: -337 02-26 12:27:10.526: W/chromium(22379):
>   external/chromium/net/spdy/spdy_session.cc:1058:
>   [0226/122710:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(1058)] Received data frame for
>   invalid stream 1 02-26 12:27:10.526: W/chromium(22379):
>   external/chromium/net/spdy/spdy_session.cc:1058:
>   [0226/122710:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(1058)] Received data frame for
>   invalid stream 1

It seems to be an error of the android browser Chromium when calling query Facebook (which using the protocol spdy)

Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same thing!

```
/chromium( 1942): external/chromium/net/spdy/spdy_session.cc:1246: [0307/015242:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(1246)] Could not parse Spdy Control Frame Header.
W/chromium( 1942): external/chromium/net/spdy/spdy_session.cc:1058: [0307/015242:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(1058)] Received data frame for invalid stream 21
W/chromium( 1942): external/chromium/net/spdy/spdy_session.cc:1058: [0307/015242:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(1058)] Received data frame for invalid stream 21
D/chromium( 1942): Unknown chromium error: -337
```

Found news about FB implementing SPDY without much news:
http://zoompf.com/2013/03/facebook-adds-spdy-support

Surprised we're not seeing more issues around.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have the same problem with the similar code under identical
   circumstances, PhoneGap, Android
2. The solution is to switch to Graph
   API. Using Graphi API the same call will be

   ```
       FB.api('/me/friends', { fields: 'id, name, gender, username' }, function (response) { ... });
   ```
3. There are a number of caveats that might
   not be applicable to you but were applicable to me

The fields named differently. “sex” is now “gender”,  for example Graph API does not
    have direct analog of is_app_user field. If you add it to the list
    of fields, you’ll get an error. There is a workaround asking
    specifically for the users who installed the app

There is paging
    implemented in response. So the response is structured a bit
    differently. If you used to pass the data for processing to
    functions you shall pass not “response”  but “response.data”, and
    watch for “response.paging”, to see if there are more friends to add
    by additional calls.